# Difference in behaviour between `DBCC TRACEON` and `QUERYTRACEON`

Tags: sql-server, cardinality-estimates, trace-flags

I am using SQL server 2014, but my database version is SQL server 2012. So I am trying to use [trace flag 2312](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2801413/enable-plan-affecting-sql-server-query-optimizer-behavior-that-can-be) to force the query optimizer to use cardinality estimator v120.

I have noticed through my own testing on a specific query:

- With this trace flag active the query takes about 20 minutes, but in SSMS results come back all at once after 20 minutes
- Without the trace flag active the query takes about 30 minutes, but the first few results come back instantly and continue to be added.

I have no issues with trace flags in SSMS, the trace flag seems to be properly set regardless of whether i set a global trace flag using `DBCC traceon(2312, -1)` or I add the option `option (Querytraceon 2312)`.

The problem is when I try to run this query through my .NET application, if my query has the `querytraceon` option, then `IDBCommand.ExecuteReader()` seems to hang until the entire query completes, which seems like what I expect given my results in SMSS. However, if I globally enable the traceflag, but remove the `querytraceon` option from my query, then `IDBCommand.ExecuteReader()` finishes right away.

To me this seems like my query is not picking up the trace flag 2312, even though it is globally enabled for all sessions.

What could cause the discrepancy here?

I have added the xml execution plan for my plan with the trace flag enabled globally:
(broken into 2 parts due to size)

- https://paste.city/98
- https://paste.city/103

The plan for the trace flag enabled using querytraceon:
(broken into 2 parts due to size)

- https://paste.city/100
- https://paste.city/102

trace flag disabled:
https://paste.city/99

Comment: A wild guess is that you don't have the same SET options in SSMS and your .NET app. Some SET options will cause the optimizer to create different plans for (i.e., same query *isn't* the same query because of different setting for some of these SET options). Again, a very wild guess but perhaps withe verifying...

Comment: Without more information Guesing is about the best anyone here is going to be able to do for you. If you'd posted your plan XML to where Erik had suggested we'd likely have an answer to yoru question by now.

Comment: Can you try both again in SSMS with also `OPTION (RECOMPILE);`? Since the text of your two queries is different, it could be that they got compiled at different times with very different stats, and now those very different plans are getting reused independently. But as has been suggested multiple times, we can make better guesses with the plans. Imagine calling your mechanic and playing an engine sound over the phone and expecting a diagnosis while refusing to bring the car in...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have tried this and it does not affect either `dbcc traceon` or `querytraceon`

Comment: Great. Well, that interface is unusably slow and once I got one of the statements copied it seems like the statement text is so long that it gets truncated before a single table is mentioned.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've switched to a different one now

Comment: I'm confused. You said you were seeing different behavior when you **enabled** trace flag 2312 globally via `DBCC TRACEON` vs. when you **enabled** trace flag 2312 through `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON)`. But then in your links you say the trace flag is enabled vs. disabled and, in fact, in the query plans, there is zero evidence that you enabled 2312 via `QUERYTRACEON`. You are missing a node like this: `<TraceFlag Value="2312" Scope="Session"></TraceFlag>`

Comment: @TiborKaraszi are these SET options user specfiic? I am using the same SQL Server user for SSMS and .NET. Im not too sure where I would look to edit these in .NET

Comment: No, they are not user-specific, they are *session* specific. I can connect twice in SSMS with the same credentials and in one session use ANSI_NULLS off, and the other turn them on. Also, the last plan you added is not complete.

Comment: Also worth noting that the same question was asked on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563431/idbcommand-executereader-not-picking-up-sql-server-trace-flags

Comment: @AaronBertrand you're a lifesaver. When I was running this on smss I was always clearing cache and using the recompile option, but realized I wasn't doing this through my .NET app. I guess without explicitly giving the querytraceon option sql server was using an old query plan possibly.

Comment: although I am curious, why is it that we have to do this when a trace flag is enable/disabled? I never noticed this being mentioned when looking up these flags

Answer (score 1):

The query you were sending from the .NET application was still likely to be using the "old" plan (which used the legacy cardinality estimator).

When you enabled the trace flag globally, and then removed the `QUERYTRACEON` hint, the query text was different, resulting in a new plan being compiled for the query.  This newly compiled plan used the newer cardinality estimator, and thus met your expectations related to the plan shape, and having results return immediately.

Changing the query text in this case had the same effect as when you added `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in SSMS while doing your testing.

Regarding your follow up question in the comments:

> although I am curious, why is it that we have to do this when a trace flag is enable/disabled?

The reason for this is that enabling trace flag 2312 globally does *not* clear the execution plan cache.  So for queries that you need to leverage the new CE, you'll need

- to manually evict those plans from the cache one by one (with [`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (plan_handle)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)),
- temporarily add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to them, or
- just clear the entire plan cache (if you need most queries to use the new CE, and your environment can handle this action).